# how to get the default size of a window in pyqt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When I create a `QMainWindow` without explicitly specifying its dimensions, PyQt will give it a -let's say- "standard size" which is not the minimum that the window can get.

Can I set this size at will in any way?

My goal is to get this "standard size" according to the currently visible widgets, when I set the visibility of some widgets on/off.

Comment: Use layouts. They will resize the parents automatically. Otherwise use `resize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidget.sizeHint` holds the recommended size for the widget. It's default implementation returns the layout's preferred size if the widget has a layout. So if your dialog has a layout, just use `sizeHint` to get the recommended size which is the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at [`QWidget.normalGeometry()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#normalGeometry-prop).
Note, the widget (or in this case, `QMainWindow`) must be first shown for this to return something other than (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

You might try this command to set size:

```
QMainWindow.setIconSize (self, QSize iconSize)
```

Alternatively, one can set a size with the given width and height using:

```
PySide.QtCore.QSize.setWidth() PySide.QtCore.QSize.setHeight()
```

Comment: I don't want to explicitly specify size. I want to get the "default size" of the window as described above. the size that the widget gets automatically when created.

Comment: I would put a routine in that looks at the active widgets and, based upon that, sets the size using the commands above.  If you want an active window, you'll have to code that activity in.

Comment: You asked, "Can I set this size at will in any way?"  The commands I showed are those that set size at will.  Best of luck.